# Loop that creates horizontally scrolling divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using jquery so that I can dynamically create a series of divs that can scroll horizontally, the problem is the  divs dont scroll horizontal and they go down.

Here is my code for the Jquery/html

```
<div id="routeContainer">
  <script type="text/javascript">

      var margin = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         $("#routeContainer").append("<div style = 'margin-left: " + margin + "px;' class = 'test'>hello world</div>");
         margin += 50;
      };
  </script>
</div>
```

and here is my CSS

```
 #routeContainer{
 width:100%;
height:100%;
background-color: #CCC;
-ms-overflow-x: auto;
/* IE8 */
overflow-x: auto;
-ms-overflow-y: hidden;
/* IE8 */
overflow-y: hidden;
display:inline-block;
white-space:nowrap;
}

.test{
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
background-color: #FFF;
position: relative;
float: left;
display: inline-block;
}
```

this is the jsFiddle I adapted my code from

http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/FPBWr/

why isnt it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you Want to make it horizontal, then have a table inside it like

```
 <div id="routeContainer">
       <table>
          <tr id="routeContainerTR">

          </tr>
       </table>    
 </div>
```

Then In javascript function add

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var margin = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

  $("#routeContainerTR").append("<td><div style = 'margin-left: " + margin +

   "px;' class = 'test'>hello world</div></td>");

  margin += 50;

  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to fix the height and width of your #routeContainer to some fixed values instead of 100%, otherwise it will expand to fit the content inside it instead of scrolling.

You also need to remove the float: left from the .test class, so that the divs will sit side by side instead of floating below each other.

This might be what you want then: http://jsfiddle.net/XasPm/

```
#routeContainer{
width:500px;
height:180px;
background-color: #CCC;
-ms-overflow-x: auto;
/* IE8 */
overflow-x: auto;
-ms-overflow-y: hidden;
/* IE8 */
overflow-y: hidden;
display:inline-block;
white-space:nowrap;
}

.test{
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
background-color: #FFF;
display: inline-block;
}
```

(Aside: I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the increasing margins. Also you mention multiple scrolling divs, but your code creates one scrolling div and fills it with multiple "hello world" divs. You should just be able to add more below it.)